# Why does this titlesec code amending subsection give an error on section?

Tags: titles, subsection

CORRECTED based on comment from Carlisle below.

I want to change the subsection header so that is has no indent. I thought this code would do it but when I compile I get undefined control sequence @secnumpunct. I'm assuming this has something to do with the numbering or numbering punctuation, but I didn't change anything about the numbering, at least I don't think I did.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
  [\vspace{-1em}\leftmargin=0pt]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Section 1}
        \subsection{Subsection 1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the error shows `\@secnumpunct` (not `\section`) is undefined

Comment: Okay, I see it now that you've pointed it out. Not being versed in these things I focused on the two things I've seen before: `undefined control' and `a control'. The rest makes no sense to me. Thank you for the correction. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `titlesec` cannot be used with `amsbook`, because this class redefines `\@startsection`.

Just look in the class to see

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \normalparindent{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

and change `\normalparindent` into `{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  {0pt}{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: I'll probably regret asking this, but where do I go to learn  how to change the way Latex controls work?

Comment: @TonyK Read the TeXbook a few times and learn how to read package code. Then try and retry.  For a book I produced I used an AMS class, but I needed to tailor it to the publisher's specs, so I had to learn how these classes do their business, in quite  a different way than the standard ones. And I believe I already found out that they are incompatible with `titlesec` for answering questions here.